# Restore all files from the commit

Tags: git, commit

I accidentally deleted all the project files and now I want to get everything back through a commit. How do I do this?

Git log shows one commit(head). There is no project on GitHub and no local copies either. My only option is this commit.

Comment: `git checkout <commitid>` ?

Comment: i try it but i see "HEAD is now at 3beb868 My" when i write "git checkout 3beb868"

Comment: You have only one commit? and you deleted the files as part of that commit?

Comment: @BlAyMid try `git revert <commit_id>`

Comment: `git checkout .` should undo most changes but you may want to use something like VS Code to do this in a visual git UI.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, as a result, I figured out and restored the files from the commit via the path to git via the git UI in IJ.

Answer (score 0):

To restore file, it is better to use the [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) command:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git restore -s <commitID> -- .
```